# To implement tags in textarea

Tags: html, angular

This is a bit vague question, so I am making a chat application where on typing `@` the users of the group pops up, the user has to select from these people., just like WhatsApp.

Now the problem is the user can also do a backspace and delete the 1 character from name. Unlike WhatsApp is the `@` is used to tag someone in the group and even a single backspace is made the whole text got deleted.

I am using Angular in the front end[image: it looks like this]

I hope you get the picture of what I am trying to convey, any leads in right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind (keydown) on the input element and also FormControl directive to follow the changes via a FormGroup.

```
<input (keydown)="handleKeyDown($event)" [formControl]="formGroup.controls['input']" />
```

Then you can implement function where you watch the backspace and its context in the input field.

```
...
formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  input: ''
});

handleKeyDown(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 46){
    console.log('Delete Key Pressed');
    if(event.target.selectionStart == event.target.selectionEnd && event.target.selectionStart == this.formGroup.get('input').value.length-1){
      //delete until @
      let lastIndex:number = this.formGroup.get('input').value.lastIndexOf('@');
      if(lastIndex != -1){
        this.formGroup.get('input').setValue(this.formGroup.get('input').value.substr(0, lastIndex));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or something like this... I did not test the code.